# DBeaver ошибка - не могу создать новое соединение

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Только скачал Dbeaver, не могу создать новое соединение, пишет: Connection refused: no further information, Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.
Connection refused: no further information

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: iana закрепила данный номер порта за программой postgresql. она у вас установлена и запущена?

Comment: Да, запущена. В pgAdmin та же самая проблема, не удается присоединиться к серверу